# Woocommerce how to remove Variation select list and show it in a custom hook

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming, product-variations, variable-product

In a Woocommerce Product Page I need to remove the Variation Select Lists from the default placement and show them y my custom hook:

> "flatsome_custom_single_product_3"

How can I do this?

I tried with this, but not working.

```
   remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation', 10 );
   add_action( 'flatsome_custom_single_product_3', 'woocommerce_single_variation', 10 );
```

Take a look at this capture to see what I mean:

[image]

Comment: Is your custom hook located on the same page? Or on a different page?

Comment: @Ruvee in the same page

Answer (score 0):

You could first remove the default variation and then add your own using the following hook:

```
remove_action('woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 30);

add_action('woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 'custom_variable_div', 15);

add_action('woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20);

function custom_variable_div(){
    # Make up your own stuff
}
```

I've tested it and it works seamlessly fine!

Comment: Where do I set my custom hook "flatsome_custom_single_product_3" ?

Comment: replace ```custom_variable_div``` with your own ```flatsome_custom_single_product_3```

Comment: Really? Interesting, haaa? Well, were you able to remove the default variation section?

Comment: The only thing I could think of, is your custom function! Does your custom function output anything? like html content?